# How do I construct an array and initialize it to the values 1 through 5 using a loop?

Tags: java

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting a NullPointException error.

```
public class Array
{
    
    private int[] val;

    public Array()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
           if (i < 4) {
               System.out.print(",");
           }
           int[] val = new int[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a local variable inside the constructor (int[] val = new int[i]) instead of using the instance variable (private int[] val). Try changing it to:

    val = new int[i];

This way you are referring to the instance variable instead of the local variable created after the if clause.

Comment: I feel that the duplicate is way above the level required to explained the basics to this OP and should be re-opened. @pradeep-simha

Comment: @leogtzr making this change still produces the same error...

Comment: @cbjdfall, you cannot use the .length property yet in the for loop, because the array hasn't been initialized, you need to initialize it first and then use it.


```
public Array() {
    this.val = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
       if (i < 4) {
           System.out.print(",");
       }
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do this is

```
public class MyArray
{
    
    private int[] val;

    public MyArray()
    {
        val = new int [5];  // create an array of 5, all zero values at this stage
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
               val [i] = i + 1;
        }
    }
```